# Awk field separator bug?

Tags: awk

This is the expected way for the awk field separator to work:

```
$ echo 'fooXbar' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="X"} {print $1}'
foo
$ echo 'fooXbar' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="X"} {print $2}'
bar
$
```

but if the FS is "-|-" then things get strange:

```
$ echo 'foo-|-bar' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="-|-"} {print $1}'
foo
$ echo 'foo-|-bar' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="-|-"} {print $2}'
|
$ echo 'foo-|-bar' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="-|-"} {print $3}'
bar
$
```

Why? Why is the $2 a "|" in the second example??

UPDATE:

```
$ echo 'foo-|-bar' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="-\|-"} {print $2}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'
|
$
```

Comment: Multi-character field separators are treated as regular expressions in awk. You should always escape them appropriately if you want the literal meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FS` is a regex: awk interprets `-|-` as "`-` or `-`".

Use `-\|-` instead. You'll need to double the backslash inside the string literal.

```
echo 'foo-|-bar' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="-\\|-"} {print $1}'
```

or

```
echo 'foo-|-bar' | awk -F '-\\|-' '{print $2}'
```