# Parse a string with multiple special asterisk characters

Tags: text-processing, awk

I try to parse my input string in a script with `awk` and I have encountered some limitations with multiple special characters like `***` and `+++`.

However, with the same script, with `:::` or `---` as delimiters, I do not have any issue.

My script:

```
input=$1
delimiter=":::"

field2=$(echo "$input" | awk -F"$delimiter" '{print $2}')
field3=$(echo "$input" | awk -F"$delimiter" '{print $3}')
echo "field2=$field2"
echo "field3=$field3"
```

Output with `:::` as a delimiter:

```
bash-3.2$ ./parse_options.sh ":::sub  option::: Main option, still:bla:"
field2=sub  option
field3= Main option, still:bla:
```

Now if I try to use `***` as a delimiter but have other isolated `*` in my string, here is what I get unfortunately: the `*bla*` is counted as an another field and that's not what I want:

```
bash-3.2$ ./parse_options.sh "***sub  option*** Main option, still*bla*"
field2=sub  option
field3= Main option, still
```

As you can see, `*bla*` do not appear in the third field, the delimiter set in `awk` is not respected in that case.

And it is the same thing with `+++` as a delimiter:

```
bash-3.2$ ./parse_options.sh "+++sub  option+++ Main option, still+bla+"
field2=sub  option
field3= Main option, still
```

**For further clarifications :**

input=`***sub  option*** Main option, still*bla*`

Expected output=

```
field2=sub  option
field3= Main option, still*bla*
```

Comment: please post input and expected output - because its difficult to provide a solution without that.

Comment: @jai_s I just added it at the end of my question

Comment: use `delimiter='\\*\\*\\*'` ... note the use of single quotes

Comment: @Sundeep I tried the double escape but with double quotes, using just single quotes as you mentioned worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
delimiter='\\*\\*\\*'

field2=$(echo "$input" | awk -F"$delimiter" '{print $2}')
field3=$(echo "$input" | awk -F"$delimiter" '{print $3}')
echo "field2=$field2"
echo "field3=$field3"

$ ./parse_options.sh "***sub  option*** Main option, still*bla*"
field2=sub  option
field3= Main option, still*bla*
```

**Further reading:**

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- [Types of quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- [escaping awk field separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116537/awk-field-separator-bug)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you replace the *** or +++ to some other symbol then use that symbol as separator

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1

formatted_input=$(echo ${input} | sed "s/\*\*\*/\|/g;s/+++/\|/g")

field2=$(echo "${formatted_input}"  | awk -F\| '{print $2}')
field3=$(echo "${formatted_input}" | awk -F\| '{print $3}')
echo "field2=$field2"
echo "field3=$field3"
```

try this...

```
$ echo "***test hello***hi test msg*this***" | awk -vFS='\\*\\*\\*' '{print "Field 2 : "$2;print "Field 3 : "$3}'
Field 2 : test hello
Field 3 : hi test msg*this
```

Comment: Yes that's a possibility but I wanted to have a more direct approach. I think that is something achievable with awk but can't figure how.
I tried to escape the * and even to double escape them but without success in the output.

Comment: modified the answer with FS variable. try that...

Comment: the single quotes were what I missed in my tries, thank you